# How do I locate a service on my server?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line-interface, service, ubuntu-18.04, pid

I installed Monit on my server, as well as the "ProtonMail Bridge".

How to know the path of the "ProtonMail Bridge" service to add it to Monit ?

ubuntu@www-example-com ~ $ ps -ef

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MKbG.png)

Comment: How exactly did you install it?

Comment: @MichaelHampton https://pychao.com/2020/06/10/update-on-using-protonmail-bridge-on-headless-wordpress-linux-servers/

Comment: That looks like a tutorial on using it. It doesn't tell anything about what you specifically did to install it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I followed the tutorial to install it https://pastebin.com/RZG0VJVT

Comment: Hm. That is quite unusual that they have provided a Debian package but ask you to start it from a shell with nohup. Actually it's bizarre. They should have included a systemd unit so that you could start it as a normal system service.

Comment: @MichaelHampton the problem is that ProtonMail does not have a version for servers without a desktop. I'm just trying to monitor if the "Bridge" is still working with Monit. But I don't know what the path to PID is.

Comment: A path and a PID are 2 different things: A path is the location of the program. A PID is a number that the program gets when you start it so that the system can keep track of it. (This number will be different every time)

Comment: I have updated my question. There are PID files but I can't find the one for "ProtonMail Bridge".

Comment: I would suggest changing the question back to the original and creating a new question for the pid-problem. Otherwise future readers will see a question answered with instructions for something completely different. This would be terribly confusing.

Answer (score 0):

- `which protonmail-bridge` will immediately show it it if it's in one of the dirs in your `$PATH`. (This will probably be the case).
- If it's not in one of those dirs `locate protonmail-bridge` will find it fast if your locate-database is up to date (it probably is)
- If the database is not up to date it will take a bit longer, you can:

  - Bring it up to date with `sudo updatedb` (recommended)
  - Or search it manually with `find . -type f -executable -name 'protonmail-bridge' -print`

Comment: `/usr/bin/protonmail-bridge` here's the output, but how do I find the PID to add it to Monit ?

Comment: That's a completely different question...I never used Monit but I have a feeling that what you are trying to do is wrong. You do know that the PID is different every time it restarts, right ? That being said: The following will show you the PID of the currently running instance:  `ps -eo pid,args | grep protonmail-bridge | grep -v grep | perl -pne 's/^\s*(\d+).*/$1/' `

Comment: I have updated my question. There are PID files but I can't find the one for "ProtonMail Bridge".

Answer (score 0):

Since you have installed a deb package, (as per the instructions for installing) type,
`dpkg -l protonmail-bridge` and press tab to complete the package name. It'll show you all the files and the paths installed by the package.